# RosJava Android rosparam files

Tags: ros, parameters, rosparam, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Is there anyway using rosjava on android to be able to load rosparam files from a config file like normal ROS? because it had to be associated in a launch file and android doesn't have that

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73117/rosjava-android-rosparam-files/) by [Attia42](https://answers.ros.org/users/5986/attia42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [ParameterLoaderNode](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/blob/kinetic/rosjava_helpers/src/main/java/org/ros/helpers/ParameterLoaderNode.java). You can send it a list of YAML files, each one with a list of (parameter, value) entries; they will be loaded to the parameter server when the node starts.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0